# Attached PDF Displaying in MailComposer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am having an Issue. I am attaching `PDF` Document to `MFMailComposer`. The issue is if i attach a `PDF` Document which contains only one page then When i am presenting the `MFMailComposer`, the attached PDF is opening and displaying. But, if i attach a `PDF` with more than one Page then it is displaying as icon.

If the pdf has one page or more number of pages i need to display as icon.

Could anyone please check it out !!!!

**It should work in iPad**

**If it is the default functionality then please link with apple documents.**

Sample Code :

```
 MFMailComposeViewController *objMFMailComposeViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
  if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
        {            
            [objMFMailComposeViewController setMailComposeDelegate:self];
            [objMFMailComposeViewController setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Generated Reports for %@",lbl_details.text]];
            NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Material Details" ofType:@"pdf"];
            NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
            [objMFMailComposeViewController addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"Material Details.pdf"];
            [objMFMailComposeViewController setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
            [self presentModalViewController:objMFMailComposeViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its is default functionality as you can try it by Email a Image from photo gallery. it shows image preview

Comment: Could you please provide with apple documents in which it had stated ?